# React Native ref.injectJavascript on WebView always undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a simple functional component with a WebView inside a TabNavigator where I'd like to inject some javascript when the tab is focused like so:

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

export default (props) => {

  const webViewRef = useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      webViewRef.current.injectJavascript('console.log("Hello World")');
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <WebView ref={webViewRef} />
  );
}
```

For some reason, `webViewRef` is always undefined in the listener.

If I do something like `<WebView ref={(r) => console.log(r)} />` I get something like the following:

[image: screenshot]

**EDIT:**

Simply adjusting the provided example -does- work, so I suppose I will have to figure out what is going on in my code:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'

export default () => {

  const webViewRef = useRef(null);

  const run = `
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    true;
  `

  setTimeout(() => {
    webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(run)
  }, 3000)

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <WebView
        ref={webViewRef}
        source={{
          uri:
            'https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview',
        }}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Adjusting the simple example and attempting to use the ref inside the listener does not work:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'

export default (props) => {

  const webViewRef = useRef(null);



  const run = `
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    true;
  `
  const handleLoadEnd = () => {
    props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      webViewRef.current.injectJavascript(run)
    })
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <WebView
        ref={webViewRef}
        source={{
          uri:
            'https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview',
        }}
        onLoadEnd={handleLoadEnd}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Edit 3: `useFocusEffect` also has same problem:

```
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      webViewRef.current.injectJavascript('alert("HI")')
    }, [props.navigation])
  )
```

Sources:

- [React Navigation: Call a function when focused screen changes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/)
- [React Native WebView: Communicating between JS and Native](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#communicating-between-js-and-native)

Comment: Could you check you can access `webViewRef.current` out of addListener?

Comment: It always seems to be undefined it's so confusing.

Comment: Can you test your code with a setTimeout with a delay of 3000-5000ms? If the ref is still undefined then something is wrong. And also you can create a useEffect within the array you pass the ref. If it's set it will be called automatically

Comment: There is definitely something weird about the way this is working with the listener - as I can use the ref if it is called directly inside `useEffect`. In the listener, even with the timeout, it is not working.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Oh man, it's really another one of those epic hair pulling days:

```
  webViewRef.injectJavascript < BAD
  webViewRef.injectJavaScript < GOOD
```

Somebody please give the last 4 hours of my life back

Comment: thank you for this, that capital S in `JavaScript` really is naughty.

Comment: Funny enough I just had one of these terrible situations today with a library where the option I needed was `lazyLoad` not `lazyload`

Comment: thanks a lot man! I literally spent hours trying to solve this smh!

Answer (score 2):

The ref will be set, if the `onLoadEnd` event has triggered. So you must adjust your code like so:

```
export default (props) => {

  const webViewRef = useRef();

  const handleLoadEnd = () => {
    props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      webViewRef.current.injectJavascript('console.log("Hello World")');
    });
  }

  return (
    <WebView ref={webViewRef} onLoadEnd={handleLoadEnd}/>
  );
}
```

I have a working example. See here https://github.com/Tracer1337/MRGVP/blob/master/vertretungsplan/components/PaginatedWebview/PaginatedWebview.js

Comment: Thankyou, this makes sense and I've added the listener to `onLoadEnd` but am still having the same issue, `webViewRef` is undefined :(

Comment: So this is not working unfortunately, and I think it can be narrowed down to the listener, please see the example in `Edit 2` of my post